# Adjust Iframe height dynamically and set scroll if content height change on client side event (Text Expand/Collapse using +/- buttons)

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll, height

I have been searching around for a solution to set scroll of iframe sourcing same domain page using javascript. I just want to have scroll on the iframe only if the content's height is greater that the window height. Came across solutions using setInterval. In IE i dont get a proper scrollheight for a page that has some content hidden. The works fine in chrome and mozila although. Also it looks like i have to set anyways max-hright of the iframe to get this code working on chrome and IE when the use click on +/- in the iframe page. I dont have controll over the source page for iframe. Also there are events where in the content height of the iframe changes at client side like expand/collapse thing. Any suggestions as to why it is happening or any other options to implement.

Iframe container (div)

```
    border: groove;border-width: thin;display:none;position:fixed;z-index:998;width:800px;background-color: white;right: 83px;top:22px;
```

Iframe style

```
    top: 20px;margin:0;padding:0
```

Javascript function that gets called based on interval to set iframe height to that content height

```
    function AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad() {


var screenHeight = $(window).height();
var iframeContentHeight;

var iframeContentwidth;

iframeContentHeight = document.getElementById("iframe_ObjectLink").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

iframeContentwidth = document.getElementById("iframe_ObjectLink").contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;


if (iframeContentHeight > (screenHeight - 47)) {
    document.getElementById("objectionMenuContentContainer_div").style.height = (screenHeight - 27) + "px";
  document.getElementById("iframe_ObjectLink").height = (screenHeight - 47);
    document.getElementById("iframe_ObjectLink").contentWindow.document.documentElement.style.overflowY = "scroll";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("objectionMenuContentContainer_div").style.height = iframeContentHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById("iframe_ObjectLink").height = (iframeContentHeight - 25);
    document.getElementById("iframe_ObjectLink").contentWindow.document.documentElement.style.overflowY = "hidden";
}

if (iframeContentwidth > 883)
    document.getElementById("iframe_ObjectLink").contentWindow.document.documentElement.style.overflowX = "scroll";
else
    document.getElementById("iframe_ObjectLink").contentWindow.document.documentElement.style.overflowX = "hidden";
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried?

Comment: iframes have to be of either fixed or percentage based height. While you can change the iframe height dynamically, you really cant do it based on the height of the content since you dont have a way to get the height of the source doc though an iframe. Anything inside the iframe is technically not part of YOUR pages DOM - Only the iframe itself is. In other words, you have no way to get iframe content height without some sort of API to get the height of the content on the other site before your DOM renders. In short, iframes suck when it comes to styling.